# call static aspx method from silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, static-methods

I would like to know if it is possible to call from my silverlight application a statick method in my web application (aspx), where the silverlight is hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight application does not have direct connection with web page because Silverlight is clientside application and your aspx page is serverside.

On the other hand it is possible to call javascript methods from Silverlight via **HtmlPage.Window.Invoke** method ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptobject.invoke(v=vs.95).aspx )
You just pass javascript function name and parameters if necessary.

Then you can obviously use AJAX (for example jquery AJAX) to send request to server and execute the method, that you need. You may want to use ASHX handlers to handle request and call your static method from there.

So basically your cooperation would look like:

*Silverlight -> Javascript -> AJAX -> Serverside processing.*